# Installing Perl DBI in SUN Solaries

Tags: linux, perl, solaris, dbi

I am trying to install perl DBI on SUN solaries 11 but I always got the following error:

```
sh: line 1: cc: not found
*** Error code 127
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `Perl.o'
```

I did the following steps:

Downloaded and extracted DBI-1.628 then in the shell command:

```
cd DBI-1.628 
make realclean 
perl Perlfile.PL
meke
```

Comment: I have already install gcc and when I type which gcc I got /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: The same compiler that was used to compile Perl (`cc`) needs to be used to compile the libraries.

Comment: how I can get it, perl was already installed I am going to install DBI, DBD

Comment: Do not use /usr/bin/perl. Install your own, somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means it cannot find a compiler on your machine.  You should add the path to the compiler to your PATH variable.  gcc and cc are not the same thing.  You should install cc.